# How to get the height of hidden html block without visibility changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have page that includes 3 tabs. In one moment you can see only current tab (it is first tab, other are hidden). In second hidden tab - hidden blocks, that includes target blocks.

I can't get height of target blocks, because they are located in hidden blocks of hidden tab.

Is there a way to get the height of hidden block without showing it with JS?

Sample:

```
<div style=display: none> Some Content </div>
```

How to get height of the above `div` without changing display property?

Comment: Im not 100% sure here but i think you need to hide it with opacity instead of not display it at all to keep the height.

Comment: Alex K. Thanks, yes, the same question.

Answer (score 0):

There's couple ways to achieve this.

1. use `opacity: 0` instead of `display: none`
2. render element somewhere else, get height and use it, but this is more complex

Comment: or visibility: hidden; for better browser support